# intermediate value theorem question on function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the function $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow[-1,1]$ is continuous. Use the intermediate value theorem to prove that there exists a $c \in [-1,1]$ such that $f(c)=c^5$. You should carefully justify each of the hypothesis of the theorem. Question is to be done very formally.

First can I just say, shouldn't $c$ be $c \in (-1,1)$ because that is what the theorem has. So I am just going to assume that it is meant to say $c \in (-1,1)$. If this is not the case, then please let me know. Also this is what my thoughts are:

$f$ is continuous and is defined by $f(x)=x^5$ for $x\in[-1,1]$ so $f(-1)=-1<0$ and $f(1)=1$.

So $f(-1)$ is not equal to $f(1)$. And $f(-1) < 0 < f(1)$. By the intermediate value theorem there exists a point $c\in(-1,1)$ such that $f(c)=0$ that is $c^5=0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The interval should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question, $c$ is not necessarily in $(-1,1)$.  For example, what if $f(x) = x$?

Also, the question asks about an arbitrary function $f(x)$, so you shouldn't define $f(x) = x^5$.

Here's a hint: consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - x^5$.  If $g(-1)$ or $g(1)$ is equal to $0$, the we're done.  Otherwise, apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: oh the function is arbitrary? I didn't know.

Comment: Well, it's an arbitrary continuous function, since the question asks to show that for *every* continuous function $f:[-1,1] \to [-1,1]$, the statement holds.

Comment: but it doesn't say 'every'...

Comment: "*Suppose that the function f:[-1,1]-->[-1,1] is continuous. Use the intermediate value theorem to prove that there exists c∈[-1,1] such that f(c)=c^5.*"  All we know about the function is that is continuous from $[-1,1]$ to $[-1,1]$, and our goal is to show that this implies that there exists a $c$ satisfying the condition.  That is, no matter which continuous $f$ we've chosen, the condition will hold.  That is, for *any* (or *every*) continuous $f$, the condition will hold.

Comment: I see thanks. Im guessing g(x) is continuous because of f(x) (saying let f:[-1,1]->[-1,1] be defined by f(x) first) and function x^5 are continuous finctions so g(x) is a continuous function by the algebra of continuous functions?

Comment: Yes.  If you add two continuous functions, you get another continuous function.

Comment: I don't get how we are done if g(-1) or g(1) is equal to 0... where does c come into this.

Comment: If $g(c)=0$, then $f(c)=c^5$

Answer (score 1):

Take $g(x)=f(x)-x^5$.

Then $g(-1)=f(-1)+1\ge 0$, while $g(1)=f(1)-1\le 0$. Using the Intermediate Value Theorem for $g$, we obtain that there exists a $c\in[-1,1]$, such that
$$
f(c)=c^5.
$$

Comment: can you make this more formal please, so I can fully understand. like how g(x) is now continuous, etc.